Filter Pivot Table - Show results Greater than X
I am looking at the number of sales per day and shift and only want to display the Units that have greater than 5 sales per day in the pivot table. I have tried to group and also use the between filter, but because of the daily grain, it messes up in the pivot table (it ignores the daily grain). I don't care to display the daily counts in my final chart based off the pivot table, but want to display the number of times in a quarter they reached their goal of 5 sales per day. Example: If they reached their goal 6 times in Q1, then the chart would display 6 for the quarter for that unit.
I can amend my data table if a helper column would help identify, but not sue how to do that.
Thanks for any help or suggestions. Brent

[Edit] in a data example, preferably using Markdown Table ; include the desired result and any attempts you made so far.

Thanks for the suggestion of the markdown table. Did not know they existed. I'll update. Thanks

I took the dataset from the pivot table, imported into Tableau where I could format as a table. Then I exported into Excel in a format I could work with.
thanks for looking!
